# Cat stooped eating what could be the cause and should I force feed him?

Tags: cats, diet

My cat is 16 years old.
About a month ago he started eating a lot less. I've tried different foods, both fresh and canned. He ate some but very little and lost a lot of weight. I took him to the vet for some blood test and he said that basically my cat is fine just old. He gave him some shots of vitamins and something to help with his appetite. After that my cat started eating again and was looking like hes gaining back the weight he lost.

About 3 days ago he stopped eating completely. He doesn't like anything he used to eat. He only drinks a small amount of water during the day.

I bought some high calorie liquid food suppose to be for cats having trouble eating after surgeries or injuries and I'm planning on force feeding him that with a syringe. Is that a good idea? Or are there other things I could try that would possible be less stressful for the cat?

What could be the cause for him to stop eating completely?

UPDATE:
Since somebody asked for and update.
The vet told there is pretty much no chance he'll recover so there is no point in running tests trying to figure out what went wrong and I had him euthanized.
All I've got left is knowing he lived a long (for a cat) and happy life and he won't suffer anymore.

Comment: if your cat stop eating for more than 24 hrs YOU NEED TO TAKE HIM TO THE VET your cat is at risk of fatty liver syndrome this might be lethal.please take a look at the linked Q&A please read the linked answers as they tell you more about the risk if a cat stop eating.

Comment: Thank you for the linked Q&A. I'm taking my cat to the vet later today and hopefully he'll get better.

Comment: At this age, it's likely to be bad news. With luck he's only ill . P.S. post an update, what did you learn from the veterinary?

Comment: @DimaTisnek updated the post with the rest of the story.

Comment: @Tomas My condolences. You made the right call.